# Updating a large data set via SQL command

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm currently working with an import file that has 460,000 rows of data within it. Each row consists of a ID and a quantity (eg. "1,120"). This information is read from the file, then should be used to update each individual row within a database (eg. UPDATE item SET quantity = QTY WHERE id = 1).

The problem I'm having, though, is actually being able to actually run the query efficiently. If I run an individual query for each line, it's really not going to work (As I've found out the hard way).

I'm not in any way a SQL user and I'm currently learning, but from what I've seen, the web doesn't seem to have any useful results on this.

I was wondering if anybody had experience with updating such a large dataset, and if so, would they be willing to share the methods that they used to achieve this?

Comment: Create a User Defined Table Type in SQL that has two columns: id and quantity. Then create a datatable in VB with two columns: id and quantity, and then send the datatable as a parameter from VB to SQL.

Comment: `If I run an individual query for each line, it's really not going to work` why is that?

Comment: What format is the import file in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

460k rows isn't a lot, so you should be okay there.

I'd recommend importing the entire dataset into a temporary table, or table variable.  To get the solution working, start by creating an actual physical table, which you can either DROP or TRUNCATE while you are getting this working.

Create the table, then import all the data into it.  Then, do your table update based on a join to this import table.

Discard the import table when appropriate.  Once this is all working how you want it to, you can do the entire thing using a stored procedure, and use a temporary table to handle the imported data while you are working with it.

Answer (score 2):

- 460000 rows is a small dataset. Really small.
- Bulk insert into tempoary table, then use an update command to run the update on the original data in one run.